# Procedure or function 'approve' expects parameter '@ApproveID', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i try to approve documents through following code

```
if (e.CommandName == "_Approve")
        {
            //using (SqlConnection con = DataAccess.GetConnected())
            using (SqlConnection con = new 
          SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"]
           .ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)
                   ((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                    Button Prove_Button = (Button)row.FindControl("BtnApprove");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approve", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", UserID));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DocID", DocID));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ApproveID", ApproveID));
                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        GrdFileApprove.DataBind();
                    }
                }

                catch
                {
                    apfi.Text = "Not Approve";



                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }


        else if (e.CommandName == "_Reject")
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new 
          SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
        ["mydms"].ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)
                    ((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                    LinkButton Prove_Button = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("Button1");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sprejectapprove", con);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID",UserID));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DocID", DocID));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ApproveID", ApproveID));
                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        GrdFileApprove.DataBind();
                    }
                }

                catch 
                {
                    apfi.Text = "Rejct";
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

and approve store procedure is

```
 @UserID int,
  @DocID int,
 @ApproveID int
as
insert into Approval(UserID,DocID,ApproveID)
VALUES(@UserID,@DocID,@ApproveID)
```

and in sql there is approve type table in which there is columns approveid and 
approve type and approve type has 3 types 1 is approve 2 reject and 3 is pending

and in approve table there is userid,docid,approveid

so when i debug the code it give me error in approve part catch

> Procedure or function 'approve' expects parameter '@ApproveID', which was not supplied.
>   any help please
>   thanku

Comment: Is this against a local database or a remote database?

Comment: Where is it? Is it attached to the project as a reference or does the database live elsewhere? Could you show your connection string?

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that `ApproveID` has a value of `null`. Due to some craziness of ADO.NET, `null` parameters *are not sent*. You need:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ApproveID", (object)ApproveID ?? DBNull.Value));
```

or simpler:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("ApproveID", (object)ApproveID ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Or even easier yet, with "dapper" it is much easier to get it right:

```
con.Execute("approve", new {
    UserID, DocID, ApproveID
}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: in approvetype there is approveid and in this i set as a primary key

Comment: @user2832406 the `(object)` here just makes the null-coalesce work. I can't see (from here) what type `ApproveID` is - but lets suppose it is a `string`: you can't null-coalesce a `string` and `DBNull`. You can, however, null-coalesce an `object`.

Comment: @user2832406 but what *type* is it ? How is `ApproveID` *declared*?

Comment: @user2832406 you're sure it isn't `int?` ? (the `?` being very important here). Basically, if this value **isn't** null (and `int` is *never* `null`), then my answer is wrong. In which case I would have to ask: exactly which line does it throw on?

Comment: @user2832406 and note: I'm talking about the `ApproveID` in the C# code, not the database column `ApproveID`, and not the sproc parameter `@ApproveID`.

Comment: there is a table approvetype columns are:approveid int,approvetype nvarchar(50),status nvarchar(50) and i fill wih following data         1 approve true ,2 reject true ,3 pending true and there is other table which is approval in this there is clolumns:userid,docid,approveid now when admin approve /reject it must going to database as 1,1,1 or 1,1,2

Comment: @user2832406 in your example, you're talking mainly about the database - it is the C# `ApproveID` that matters; are you absolutely sure (as in, you've used a break-point to inspect the value of `ApproveID` at the time when adding it) that it is not null?

Comment: yes when i set a breakpoint and press f11 then in userid,docid,approveid it gives me null value

Comment: and u share another sol when i apply this it give me error " 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"    in execute  i apply under this statment            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: @user2832406 you just said "it gives me null value" - great! then that is exactly the problem. Null would be bad here, and is exactly what I was saying is the problem. Re the `Execute` : that example is via "dapper" - you would need to *add dapper* for that: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper . Of course the other thing to consider is: *why* are those values `null`, and should then in fact be non-null, and if so, what values should they be, and why did they not already have values, etc...

Comment: @user2832406 dapper is the name of a library developed by Stack Exchange to assist with ado.net - making it much more convenient, but without the performance overhead of full ORMs like EF or NHibernate